# Owl carousel 2 get visible elements

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

How can I get the visible items of an Owl Carousel 2?

On the Owl Carousel 1, I was able to get it with:

```
jQuery('#my-carousel').data('OwlCarousel').visibleItems;
```

But that doesn't work anymore. Even the data calling has changed to `('owl.carousel')`, that's what I already figured out.

I took the example from the Owl Carousel 1 Documentation and adjusted the parts for the new Version:
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/sync.html

I have all, just the part of the visible elements is still a problem.

I tried several things but I wasn't able to get visible elements.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I think you could just reference the `items` option on the element instance http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the visible items have the css classes "owl-item" and "active", so use `$("#my-carousel .owl-item.active")` to get an array of jQuery objects, and `$("#my-carousel .owl-item.active").get()` to get an array of DOM objects.

Answer (score 0):

in the options set center:true. This adds class center to visible and active slider item. Then you can easily select it with .center selector

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend you using version 1. But here is answer anyways.
You do it like this for owl 2:

```
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
   console.log(": ", e.relatedTarget.settings.items)
})
```

If you want to trigger on page load add event before initialising. Like this.

```
var owl = $('#yourDiv')
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
   //console.log("vis: ", e.property.value.items) // don't use this.
   console.log("vis: ", e.relatedTarget.settings.items)
})
owl.owlCarousel({settings})
```

**Edit:** 
Sorry. This only works initially. Because initial type of `e.property.value` is Object. But later it is integer. Javascript right. I will update if i find solution.

**Update**: I updated answer. It works now.